# Duty to disclose new construction to home buyers?

Tags: real-estate, homeownership

I recently bought a new house. After moving in I found out from some local people that a large subdivision is planned to be constructed immediately behind my property within the next 5 years. This wasn’t disclosed to me by the home sellers, either real estate agent, or our lawyers.

This is a large subdivision which will clear a large section of forest along a river and will effectively double the population of the small town.

Did anyone have a duty to disclose that information to me? Or was it my responsibility to review public planning notices I. The area? The issue as I see it is the previous home owners would have been consulted as part of the planning process, but now I’ll be facing the consequences of the development without having a voice in the process.

Comment: did you see a section on the disclosure form about property that wasn't the specific property being purchased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parties involved in the sale of your property only have a duty to disclose that which is required by law (jurisdiction-dependent) about the property being purchased. You are then left to discern relevant facts about nearby lots. I would not assume that the previous owner was consulted or that there was any voting involved, though one often learns of future development plans from the neighborhood grapevine. Huge-scale development projects often have to hold hearings and a commission approves a project (or not), and that would be a public record open for inspection.

Answer (score 1):

> Did anyone have a duty to disclose that information to me?

No.

> was it my responsibility to review public planning notices [in the]
> area?

Yes.